# Matlab linprog error - The number of rows in A must be the same as the number of elements of b

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

Hi I have the following code for a linprog optimisation.

```
for j = 1:2

 for i = 1:24
   for K = 1:3
      for M = 1:3

   PV_output(:,:,:) = real(PV_power_output(:,:,:));
         WT_output(:,:,:) =  WT_power_output(:,:,:);

         PVenergy = sum(sum(PV_output(:,:,1)));
         WTenergy = sum(sum(WT_power_output(:,:,1)));


          f= [((CRF*CC_PV)/PVenergy)+OM_PV; ((CRF*CC_WT)/WTenergy)+OM_WT];

         A(:,:,:) = [-PV_output(:,:,K) -WT_output(:,:,M)];


            b(:,:) = -Demand(j,i);

           lb = zeros(2,1);


           ub = [max_PV_area/PV_area max_WT_area/WT_area]';

      end
   end
  end
 end

            x(:,j,i,K,M) = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub)
```

Where WT_output and PV_output are 3 dimensional 365x24 arrays and Demand is 365x24

I am trying to optimise x1 and x2 for each of the 365x24 elements of Demand and for each dimension so as to find the optimum K and M combination

However as the code currently stands I keep getting the error - "The number of rows in A must be the same as the number of elements of b."

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, can you try to provide a shorter code in order to understand the problem you get? You can also indent it well. 
If your problem is just the usage of `linprog`, then all for-loops are useless and you should ask a question entirely related to this problem. Then, when you will have a working code, feel free to come back to ask questions about optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your workspace say about the sizes of A and B? ChrisJamesC right.. It happened with me too.. I forgot to transpose the matrix while performing operations. Try to check the workspace at each step by placing breakpoints. That might help

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation of `linprog`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/optim/ug/linprog.html) states that:

> x = linprog(f,A,b) solves min f'*x such that A*x ≤ b.

So, clearly the number of rows in A must be the same as the number of elements of b as A can be a matrix whereas b is a vector

If your question is "why don't I have the good size?" just try to print the size of the vectors/matrices at each step in order to see where the mistake is (it happens a lot that you forget to transpose a matrix for example)